# Send axios put request to multiple end points by path to express server

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to send an axio put request from my react component to my express server.
my code looks like this at the moment:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/restaurants/${targetId}`
```

and my server side looks like this:

```
app.use('/restaurants');
const router = express.Router()
router.put('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    //perform update here

});
```

and this works.

but I would like to change my route to this:

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/restaurants/removeFromFavourite/${targetId}`, {comment, 'too spicy'})
```

or this

```
axios.put(`http://localhost:3001/restaurants/addToFavourite/${targetId}`, {comment, 'test great!'})
```

How should I modify my router so that on express server so that

1. I have one end point for removeFromFavourite and one end point for addToFavourite.
2. parse the comment data.

I tried adding the following:

```
router.put('/removeFavourite/:id', (req, res)=>{
    

});

router.put('/addToFavourite/:id', (req, res)=>{
    

});
```

but they all went to

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res)=>{
    //perform update here

});
```

thanks

Comment: I recreated your code in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-bird-zistfo). Every route that you described, works as intended. Probably you haven't changed the routes in you `axios` call?

Comment: Hi AhmCho, thank you for your help. Yes, you were right, I was sending incorrect put request from my react component. It is now hitting the right end points now.